# MATE 18.04 Mutiny panel layout duplicates top panel icons/applets

Tags: 18.04, mate, panel, ubuntu-mate, mutiny

I installed MATE desktop on a vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 installation that had been upgraded from 16.04, using `apt install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop` (as per the instructions on [wiki.mate-desktop.org/download#ubuntu](https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download#ubuntu)), because the [Mutiny panel layout](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/choosing-and-changing-panel-layouts-ubuntu-mate-18-04/16502) provides my favorite user experience on a Linux desktop (along with the sadly defunct Unity).

I can apply the Mutiny layout using MATE Tweak, but after a reboot the icons on the top panel appear duplicated, as per the screenshot below:

[image: ubuntu mate mutiny layout bug]

Additionally, when I press the `Super` (Windows) key and the HUD is displayed, it doesn't disappear after I click an icon nor if I press the key again, it just stays like this:

[image]

Additionally, if I use a keyboart shortcut - for example, I use `Ctrl+R` to open a terminal and `Super+E` for file explorer - the corresponding **app is launched twice**.

This also happens if I reset the panel layout (e.g. by switching to something like Netbook and then back to Mutiny) and then logout and login.

**EDIT 1:**

I removed MATE Desktop using `sudo apt remove --purge --autoremove ubuntu-mate-* mate-*`, rebooted, then `apt update` and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`, to reinstall as per @N0rbert's suggestion in the comments. However, after rebooting the desktop still has duplicated items (screenshot below). If I use Mate Tweak to change the layout to Mutiny, it displays fine, but after logging out and back in the panel icons are duplicated again.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I executed `dconf reset -f /org/mate/` as suggested, then used MATE Tweak to set the layout to Mutiny, and everything looked fine until I logout/login or reboot, after which the panel icons are duplicated, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please use task installation with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`. It is correct way of Ubuntu MATE installation. If problem persists, then ping me back.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert , I edited my question following your comment, the top panel still displays duplicate items.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce this behaviour. And do not have ideas why it happens. I see your question on [Ubuntu MATE Community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mutiny-panel-layout-duplicates-top-panel-icons-applets-on-18-04/19957?u=norbert_x), I hope you'll solution there :)

Comment: @N0rbert , I appreciate the huge effort you put into this issue, but this is my main work laptop so I need to go with a safer but still good option: the Netbook layout with some minor tweaks :) When 20.04.1 is out I'll do a clean install of Ubuntu MATE :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to reset all MATE settings. It is safe as you have freshly installed it.
The command to reset MATE settings is the following:

```
dconf reset -f /org/mate/
```

and then set Mutiny layout from MATE Tweak (`mate-tweak`) again.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer after doing that, the icons are still duplicated after logout/login or reboot.